# How does a packet get corrupted in a network?

Tags: layer1

I recently read about CRC, a checksum to detect package corruption and drop corrupted packages.
But how does a packet in an IP-based network get corrupted in the first place?

Comment: Your question basically boils down to "Why are systems imperfect?" There's implementation mistakes, environmental conditions... Systems don't run in perfect isolation. No matter how good a system you make, it will still be affected by random noise from the environment - cosmic rays, EM interference, "that faulty device on the network/power supply"... Even your computer's RAM/HDD has error-detection and correction mechanisms, and that's right there in your computer's box - would you expect communication over thousands of kilometers to be *less* faulty?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Packets are long streams of binary numbers (`zeros` and `ones`).

The `zeros` and `ones` are usually changes of an electric signal, specifically voltage changes.

To simplify, suppose that `0` is *0 volts*  and `1` is  represented  alternatively as *5 volts* and *-5 volts*.

Then a long string of zeros and ones will look like this in terms of voltage variations in the cable:

[image]

As you can see, the first `1` is 5 volts, but the next `1`is -5 volts. This is neccesary to avoid that a long string of `1`s energizes the communication line.

If the cable is exposed to electromagnetic interference, then the voltage levels can be altered. If a -5 volts value becomes -2 volts then the receiver can't identify it precisely as a `zero` or a `one`.

If your data cable runs for a long stretch parallel to power cables, then the power cable can cause interference to the data cable and induce errors.

Comment: This gets worse for multi level PAM encodings, like 5 level 1000BASE-T or 10GBASE-T with 16 levels. Just look at one of their eye diagrams: http://0397dc3.netsolhost.com/images/wp_ChooseCAT5/wp_ChooseCAT5_2.jpg

Comment: WiFi interference is maybe more obvious/likely. Most wireless systems include some level of FEC because there is often some interference and the parity overhead is worth it to avoid the massive time hit that giving a bad packet to higher layers might make as they need to retry.